# problem in css of the code want two divs to appear side by side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
 <div className="Emp">
                <div className=" ml-5 flex mt-8 h-36  ">
                    <div className=" bg-slate-400 w-56 p-20 m-5 rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div className=" bg-slate-400 w-56 p-20 m-5 rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div className=" bg-slate-400 w-56 p-20 m-5 rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div className=" bg-slate-400 w-56 p-20 m-5 rounded-lg"></div>
                </div>
                <div className='boxwithcalender'>
                    <div className="shadow-xl mt-24 rounded-xl w-[50rem] ml-15 h-96 p-10 m-10  bg-slate-400">
                        <h1>employee</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className='calenderdiv'>
                        <Calendar onChange={setDate} value={date} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='Emp2 flex'>
                <div className="shadow-xl  rounded-xl w-[50rem] ml-15 h-96 p-10 m-10 bg-slate-400  ">
                    <h1>start/end time</h1>
                    <div className="flex">
                        <div className="flex-col ">
                            <input className="rounded-xl p-5 m-4 " placeholder="start"></input>
                            <input className="rounded-xl p-5 m-4 " placeholder=""></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex-col ">
                            <input className="rounded-xl p-5 m-4 " placeholder="end"></input>
                            <input className="rounded-xl p-5 m-4 " placeholder="comment"></input>

                        </div>
                       
                    </div>

                    <button className="bg-white p-4 m-4 hover:bg-blue-950 ml-64 rounded-xl">Start/end</button>
                </div>
               
                </div>
              
                <div className="shadow-xl  rounded-xl w-[50rem] ml-15 h-96 p-10 m-10 bg-slate-400">
                    <h1>All task</h1>
                    <div className="bg-white w-[45rem] h-14 rounded-xl p-4 m-2"></div>
                </div>
                <div className='flex-col w-80 ml-[55rem]'>
                    <div className="flex-col  ">
                      <Emplogs/>
                        </div>
                   
    </div>
            </div>
```

I want my

```
                    <div className="flex-col  ">
                      <Emplogs/>
                        </div>
```

```
                this part should come on left side of my both emp2 div but it is coming under the two divs [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmiuk.png) but i want them to be side by side
```

I want my employee logs to come on side of my other divs. I want to appear my employeelogs to appear on the left side of my components.[Want my componenet on the left side of this].(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Twfj.png)

Comment: So you will first need to create a bare example on replicating it. Here is one for you : https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZTQmv6M6E8 Add the remaining place holder and then update the question, Make a snip and mark the expected output. Show us what you have tried, we can work on from that. I have updated a part of answer also, check the link for a solution idea.

Comment: no .. this approach i already tried but here is the problem if the size of my this component (emplogs)become greater than the right side one then it creates a unnecessary gap which i do not want so i tried to combine my two divs and then applying flex but it all becomes a mess. want some solution

Comment: So what you have to do is to apply the overflow for the emplogs component and make it scrollable. that will work. You will have to restrict the size of the main component and make it ```overflow-y: scroll``` Maybe that should work. I still do not have a clear idea on what components we are working with. So if that info is provided maybe it can help